# jQuery - get nested object from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I trying get nested object (current_time) from JSON.

```
{
  "ip": "134.201.250.155",
  "hostname": "134.201.250.155",
  "time_zone": {
    "id": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "current_time": "2018-03-29T07:35:08-07:00",
    "gmt_offset": -25200,
    "code": "PDT",
    "is_daylight_saving": true
  }
}
```

I have a script like this, but nested object dont show.

```
$.getJSON(ipAdressUrl, function(data) {
    $('#ip-data').html('<p>' + data.city + '</p>'),
    $('#ip-data').append('<p>' + data.region_name + '</p>'),
    $('#ip-data').append('<p>' + data.zip + '</p>'),
    $('#ip-data').append('<p>' + data.time_zone.current_time + '</p>');
});
```

Console.log give me a feedback data.time_zone is undefined. So I trided

```
...
$('#ip-data').append('<p>' + data.time_zone.('current_time') + '</p>');
...

OR

...
$('#ip-data').append('<p>' + data.time_zone.(1) + '</p>');
...
```

But without the desired result. Can anyone please tell me how to get to a specific element in a nested array?

Comment: Either way you'll get an error because time_zone is undefined and you can't read properties from undefined. Anyways, you can use square brackets like `data.time_zone['current_time']` but no point

Comment: When you console.log(data), what do you get. Please put that full object for reference to understand the shape of the data.

Comment: I tried to write data to the console and the object returned to me. I understand that I do not have access to the premium time display feature. Thank you very much, but I'm a fool. If I had the option to view the time functions, which approach is better? Concatenation or use of square brackets.